# Interate through a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to upsample my data. It is hourly data that I want to turn into 5 minute data by resampling and filling in the missing data with a linear interpolation between the hours.

[Wind_locations.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100778374/Wind%20Data/Wind_Locations.csv), the data frame has a column called 'CH'. I want to iterate through each row of 'CH' and  subtract the next row from the current. This is how I think it should work, but it is not, any suggestions?

I tried using
`data = pd.read_csv('Wind_Locations.csv')`
`data.CH.resample('5min', how='sum')`

But I get the error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex`

Any suggestions?

Comment: When considering calculations involving subsequent and preceding rows you should consider using `shift`, this is what is designed for

Comment: Thanks! what if I want to add 11 rows between each of the original rows?

Comment: You mean you want to add 11 rows together or just iterate over 12 rows and for each add the next row? For the latter case use `data.CH.shift()`

Comment: My existing data is wind speed for every hour, i.e. 0:00, 1:00, 2:00..., I want to create a new dataFrame that has rows for every 5 minutes, i.e. 0:00, 0:05, 0:10, 0:15, etc... With the new 5 minute rows adjusting linearly between each hour

Comment: Ah OK, in that case you want to look at [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), something like `data.CH.resample('5min', how='diff')` not sure if it should be `diff` or `sub`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('Wind_Locations.csv')
length = len(data.CH)

# create series with nans
new = pd.Series(np.empty(length*11-1) * np.nan)
# iterate over data's values and assign to every 12th value of new
for i in range(length):
    new.iloc[i*12] = data.iloc[i]
# fill in nans with interpolated values
new = new.interpolate()
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it gave me the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: This seems to work for me, not very elegant but it worked:  `CH = pd.Series(np.empty(length*12) * np.nan)
    for i, row in enumerate(data.CH):
        CH[i*12] = data.CH[i]
    CH = CH.interpolate()`

Comment: Sorry for the late response @andrewrmunro. I didn't notice (use tags to contact the user). Your error means you are using an outdated version of Pandas. If you upgrade to the latest, the example will work.